# How do I split this into a separate if statement?

Tags: python

I'm trying to split the following code into a separate if statement.

```
def second_half(s):
    return s[len(s)//2 if len(s)%2 == 0 else ((len(s)//2)+1):]
```

I've already tried doing the following:

```
def second_half(s):
    if len(s) % 2 == 0:
        return s[len(s)//2]
    else:
        return s[((len(s)//2)+1):]
```

and receive the following output in my doctest (although majority of my other tests passed):

```
Failed example:
    second_half("abcdef")
Expected:
    'def'
Got:
    'd'
```

Would appreciate any help. Cheers.

Comment: Just add a colon behind `len(s)//2` in the if case like above and like in the else case...

Comment: You just missed the slice operator `:` in the first if condition @puppyonkik, check my answer below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your original list-comprehension code, the start index of the slice is calculated and the last index is taken as `(len(s)`

But when you translate this into two if-statements, You forgot the slice operator `:` in the the first `if` condition, which caused only one element to be returned, but what you want is the whole slice in both if conditions, which will happen when you do `return s[len(s)//2:]` instead of `return s[len(s)//2]` in the first `if` condition

So the updated code will be

```
def second_half(s):

    if len(s) % 2 == 0:
        #Added the missing slice
        return s[len(s)//2:]
    else:
        return s[((len(s)//2)+1):]
```

And the code will work as expected

```
print(second_half('abcde'))
#de
print(second_half('abcdef'))
#def
```

Answer (score 0):

whats happening here:

```
len(s)//2 if len(s)%2 == 0 else ((len(s)//2)+1)
```

> **Ternary operator expression:**
>
> syntax:
>
> *value_when_true **if** condition **else** value_when_false*

this part of code will return integer (some_integer)

and then you will have:

```
 s[some_integer:] # a[start:] items start through the rest of the array
```

> **Slicing strings:**
>
> Syntax:
>
> *substring = original_string[first_pos:last_pos]*

```
def second_half(s):
    if len(s) % 2 == 0:
        n=len(s) // 2
    else:
        n=(len(s)//2)+1

    return s[n:]

print (second_half("abcdef"))


def second_half(s):
    if len(s) % 2 == 0:
        return s[len(s)//2:]
    else:
        return s[len(s)//2)+1]
```

output:

```
def
```

Answer (score 0):

As commented, your first return is missing the colon.
This is called `list slicing`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation#509295) for more info.

```py
def second_half_original(s):
    return s[len(s)//2 if len(s)%2 == 0 else ((len(s)//2)+1):]

def second_half_split(s):
    if len(s) % 2 == 0:
        return s[len(s) // 2:]
    else:
        return s[len(s)//2 + 1:]
```

Result:

```py
>>> def second_half_original(s):
...     return s[len(s)//2 if len(s)%2 == 0 else ((len(s)//2)+1):]
...
>>> def second_half_split(s):
...     if len(s) % 2 == 0:
...         return s[len(s) // 2:]
...     else:
...         return s[len(s)//2 + 1:]
...
>>> s = 'abcdef'
>>> print('Old\t{old}\nNew\t{new}'.format(
...        old=second_half_original(s),
...        new=second_half_split(s)
...     )
... )
Old     def
New     def
```